# Background with curved line, Is it possible?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-shapes

Should I spend a time to find a solution in CSS to apply it, or just added as a static background image.

I need to know if I can do something like in the attached image in CSS or not? if yes how, please?

[image: background with curved line.]

Comment: Use `SVG` for such shapes.

Comment: SVG for curves that is stretched to a 100% ... a CSS only solution is not available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SVG` is the recommended way to create such shapes. It offers simplicity and scale-ability.

We can use `SVG`'s `path` element to create a shape like above and fill / stroke it with some solid color, gradient or a pattern.

Only one attribute `d` is used to define shapes in `path` element. This attribute itself contains a number of short commands and few parameters that are necessary for those commands to work.

Following code will create the above shape:

```
<path d="M-10,43
         Q7,40 18,30
         T42,41 T65,64 T92,32 T133,31 T167,17 T218,61 
         V240 H-180 Z" />
```

Below is a brief description of `path` commands used in above code:

- `M` command is used to define the starting point. It appears at the beginning and specify the point from where drawing should start.
- `Q` and `T` commands are used to draw curves.
- `V` and `H` commands are used to draw straight lines.
- `Z` command is used to close current path. It draws a straight line from current point to the starting point to close the shape.

**Output Image:**

[image: Curvy lines background]

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<svg width="175" height="230" viewBox="0 0 175 230" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad" x2="0" y2="1">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f5e2ed" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path stroke="#f280ab" stroke-width="3" fill="url('#grad')"
        d="M-10,43
           Q7,40 18,30
           T42,41 T65,64 T92,32 T133,31 T167,17 T218,61 
           V240 H-180 Z" />
</svg>
```

**Useful Resources:**

Below are some useful links for `SVG`:

- [Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial)